# ImageView in back of UITextView not clipping to bounds

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uitextview

In order to get a background image in my `UITextView` I created a `UIImageView` in code, populated it with the image I wanted, added it as a `subView` of the `UITextView`, and sent it to the back.  This works on some screens, but on others it looks like this.
[image] .

Look at the `UITextFields` above it to get an idea of what it is supposed to look like.
Here is my code.

```
let img = UIImageView(frame: self.bioTextView.bounds)
img.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "text_field_bio")
self.bioTextView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
self.bioTextView.addSubview(img)
self.bioTextView.sendSubview(toBack: img)
self.bioTextView.textContainerInset.left = 10
```

How do I get the right side of the image to clip to the trailing boundary so that it isn't extending past the UITextview.

EDIT:
Here is an edit including an image of what happens when I Include this code.

```
self.bioTextView.layer.borderWidth = 1
self.bioTextView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
```

[image]

Comment: What are the bounds for the `bioTextView`? My first instinct is that it's much wider than the other text fields, because it appears to be clipping the left side.

Comment: bioTextView shares leading and trailing edges with the TextFields

Comment: the textviews are also added by code? Could be that when the imageView is added, the bounds of the textView are incorrect.

Comment: The textViews are not added in code.  They are layed out in Storyboard, and I reference them with an IBOutlet

Comment: @GabeSpound can you use this code `bioTextView.layer.borderWidth = 1` and `bioTextView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor` and post the image result, to see what is going on

Comment: @ReinierMelian I included it in the edit.

Comment: If you want rounded corner UITextFields you can simply use `myTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 10;` and `myTextField.clipsToBounds = YES;` Assuming your blue rounded corner text fields is one solid blue colour. You don't need to use images to get rounded corners in this case.

Comment: @GabeSpound can you share your background image, for download? in order to test what is happing?

Comment: @ReinierMelian Here ( https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5DcsvTLii9WVlBvdDhfM0t3ZHM/view?usp=sharing )

Comment: @Zhang when I get home, I'll give it a shot.  If it works, i'll include it in my final answer, for it is a much better solution, but I'm still going to try and get it to work the way i originally intended, so I can figure out whats going on.

Comment: @GabeSpound if you want to go for the original solution, then it looks like your bio bg image is too big.  The image view's frame is bigger than the containing bio field. You need can set `img.contentMode = UIContentModeScaleAspectFit` to make the image view's image fit the bounds of the bio field. You might also want to make the frame of the image view the same as the bio field's frame.

Comment: @Zhang The frame of the imageView is the same as the TextView, that's what's confusing.  I'll try changing the content mode.

Answer (score 0):

The comment by @Zhang solved my problem.  Because the background image was simply a solid color, it was much easier just to round the corners with `myTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 10`, clip it to bounds with `myTextField.clipsToBounds = true`, and then setting the background color with `myTextField.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor`